# Android ListView losing state of check boxes when view is scrolled

Tags: android, listview

I have managed to get my application to update my database when the state of a check box is changed, but when I scroll my application the state of the check boxes change.

My question is: how can I save the state of the check boxes so that they will not change when the view is scrolled?

Here's my cursor adapter.

```
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
     mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
             context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.wildlifelist, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img); 
    holder.mname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maori);   
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);    
    holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
    holder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

    view.setTag(holder);    
    return view;    
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    final long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_ID));

    byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_IMG));
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));

    holder.mname.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_MNAME)));
    holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_NAME)));
    holder.status.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_STATUS)));

    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {   
            if (isChecked) {        
                Log.w("Debug","RowID: " + rowId + ", isChecked: " + isChecked); 
                DBhelper.updateRow(rowId, 1);
            }
            else {
                Log.w("Debug","RowID: " + rowId + ", isChecked: " + isChecked);
                DBhelper.updateRow(rowId, 0);
            }   
        }
    });
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    TextView mname;
    TextView name;
    TextView status;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `array` or a `map` to bind the check state of each item in the view. The code should look somewhat like this.

```
CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    Map<Long, Boolean> checkState = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                 context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

         ///set other views

         holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); //unregister the check listener

         //I like to assume all views are unchecked by default
         Boolean checked = checkState.get(rowId);
         checked = (checked == null ? false : checked);

         holder.check.setChecked(checked);

        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {   
                //save the check state
                checkState.put(rowId, isChecked);

                if (isChecked) {        
                    Log.w("Debug","RowID: " + rowId + ", isChecked: " + isChecked); 
                    DBhelper.updateRow(rowId, 1);
                }
                else {
                    Log.w("Debug","RowID: " + rowId + ", isChecked: " + isChecked);
                    DBhelper.updateRow(rowId, 0);
                }   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but there are still issues with check boxes losing their state. I had to change `Cursor cursor` to `final Cursor cursor` because I cannot reference cursor because it is a non-final variable from with-in the onCheckedChanged method, could this be what is what is causing this issue?

Comment: @FusionFox I'd advise you share the complete code so I can check for the fault. If it's too large, use pastebin or sth

Comment: @FusionFox On a second thought, if the cursor is not completely loaded when attached to the adapter, then it *may* be the cause. In this case, a Map<Long, Boolean> would be better. So you can track the check state for each row id

Comment: How would I go about implementing a Map<Long, Boolean>?

Comment: @FusionFox I have changed the answer using a Map, take a look

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView reuses rows as you scroll. The BindView() method hands you a row (possibly that is being reused) and allows you to set it up according to properties from your cursor object. It doesn't look like you are setting holder.check in BindView() and this is probably why they are incorrect when the ListView is scrolled.